# Lattice FPGA: Mach X02 7000 Can it be used for DSP?

Tags: fpga, dsp, lattice

I have a MachX02 7000 having 6800 LUT's.

I want to implement DSP algorithm involving floating-point DSP algorithm on 2 14 bit ADC input data.

Is it possible to perform on this FPGA with low LUT's, No DSP blocks and 2-bit arithmetic function support per slice of 2 LUT's.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes you can.
Will it fit? Depends on your algorithm and implementation. Will it be fast? Depends on your algorithm and implementation.

Comment: Unless you *explicitly can name a very specific **technical** reason* that you want to use floating point, it's certainly the wrong choice here. Your ADC gives you 14 bits of dynamic range. Converting that fixed-point representation to floating point gives you no advantages, and just makes everything harder to do in an FPGA. Simply: don't.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks for pointing it out. Makes sense. I'll stick with fixed point operation only.

Comment: @Botnic The project has yet to start, hence I don't have a specific algorithm for it. But there surely will be some FFT digital filter plus phase measurement and error analysis between I/Q signal inputs. I'm suspicious because a small project takes an avg of 1-1.3k LUTs. If I account for resources for multipliers and adder chains/tree it might take more resources available. It has 6.8k LUTs but we only use 80% of it as a rule of thumb for the compiler to have enough space to route the design with low timing issues thus a further reduce in available resources.